# wikitude titanium SDK sample

Tags: titanium, wikitude

I was trying to use wikitude samples in titanium studio, it loads without any errors and works perfectly except that it does not detect any target images and i always see "loading" on the top when the camera shows up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return back to a previous commit,

`Example:`

```
git checkout 42bc70b8ee2d20f2aa1b7d6af7ea2a679b1ac6bd
```